# Parameters in Optimization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

---

> $\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{maximize}}[f(x)]=x_1^2+x_2^2$ subject to $a_1^2\leq2x_1^2+4x_2^2\leq a_2^2$ where the parameters satisfy $0<a_1<a_2$

---

I've never come across this type of optimization problem before as it has an interval with parameters. I can't seem to figure out how to approach this question. I want to get the values of x. I first tried separating the interval into two inequalities to use them as constraints:
$$2x_1^2+4x_2^2\leq a_2^2$$
$$2x_1^2+4x_2^2\geq a_1^2$$

But I couldn't go far unfortunately. I would appreciate any form of hint or help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are meant to solve the problem symbolically w.r.t $a_1$and $a_2$. The conditions are just a way for the person who created this exercise to tell you that the problem is assumed feasible (had $a_2$ been smaller than $a_1$ (and both non-negative) the problem would trivially be infeasible.)

Comment: Yeah I do get that. I tried solving it using the standard Lagrange approach but I couldn't get that far with it because of the interval. Could you elaborate a bit more on how you would set up the problem to find x?

Comment: There is really nothing special here. You have two quadratic constraints, and thus you need two dual variables and then proceed as usual. If you have tried but failed, you would have to show what you have done. People will not give you the solution to an exercise, but might hint where you have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think is useful to look at the problem and think about which constraint will bind.

You want to maximize $x_1^2 + x_2^2$. So you are giving $x_1$ and $x_2$ the same weight.

Morover, note that your constraints say that you need to use at minimum $a_1^2$ and at maximum $a_2^2$ of your $(x_1,x_2)$. Those enter squared in both constraints, so the constraints depend only on their absolute value.

Since you are maximizing a quantity, do you think that at the solution of the maximization problem $(x_1,x_2)$ will be equal to the lower bound ($a_1^2$), the upper bound ($a_2^2$) or neither?

Can you go on from here and find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $a_1$ and $a_2$ can have any value without restriction.

Maximise $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ subjected to $2x_1^2+4x_2^2-a_2^2\leq0$ and $-2x_1^2-4x_2^2+a_1^2\leq0$.

By assuming $y_1=x_1, y_2=x_2, y_3=a_1$ and $y_4=a_2$, this can be rewritten as

Maximise $y_1^2+y_2^2$ subjected to $2y_1^2+4y_2^2-y_4^2\leq0$ and $-2y_1^2-4y_2^2+y_3^2\leq0$.

Lagrangian is given by

$L(y,\lambda)=(y_1^2+y_2^2)-\lambda_1(2y_1^2+4y_2^2-y_4^2)-\lambda_2(-2y_1^2-4y_2^2+y_3^2)$

First-order partial derivatives of Lagrangian:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_1}=2y_1-4\lambda_1 y_1+4\lambda_2 y_1$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_2}=2y_1-8\lambda_1 y_2+8\lambda_2 y_2$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_3}=-2\lambda_2 y_3$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_4}=2\lambda_1 y_4$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1}=2y_1^2+4y_2^2-y_4^2$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2}=-2y_1^2-4y_2^2+y_3^2$

Possible cases of optimum point:

1. Neither of the constraints are active at the optimum point.
2. The first constraint is active at the optimum point.
3. The second constraint is active at the optimum point.
4. Both the constraints are active at the optimum point.

For case 1:
The stationary point would be the solution that satisfies $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_1}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_2}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_3}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_4}=0$, $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=0$.

For case 2:
The stationary point would be the solution that satisfies $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_1}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_2}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_3}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_4}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1}=0$ and $\lambda_2=0$, and $\lambda_1$ should be positive.

For case 3:
The stationary point would be the solution that satisfies $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_1}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_2}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_3}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_4}=0$, $\lambda_1=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2}=0$, and $\lambda_2$ should be positive.

For case 4:
The stationary point would be the solution that satisfies $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_1}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_2}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_3}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_4}=0$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1}=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2}=0$, and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ should be both positive.

Assuming that second-order conditions satisfy, an optimum, if exists, should lie within one of these four cases.

---

We have assumed that $a_1$ and $a_2$ can be any numbers without restriction. But in the problem we have $0<a_1<a_2$. Assuming $0\leq a_1\leq a_2$ instead of $0<a_1<a_2$, the problem would become

Maximise $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ subjected to $2x_1^2+4x_2^2-a_2^2\leq0$, $-2x_1^2-4x_2^2+a_2^2\leq0$, $-a_1\leq 0$ and $a_1-a_2\leq 0$

By assuming $z_1=x_1, z_2=x_2, z_3=a_1$ and $z_4=a_2$, this can be rewritten as

Maximise $z_1^2+z_2^2$ subjected to $2z_1^2+4z_2^2-z_4^2\leq0$, $-2z_1^2-4z_2^2+z_3^2\leq0$, $-z_3\leq 0$ and $z_3-z_4 \leq 0$.

Now, repeat the same process with these additional two constraints. Since there are four constraints, there would be $2^4=16$ cases. A statoinary point, if exists, should lie within those cases.

---

We have assumed $0\leq a_1\leq a_2$ instead of $0<a_1<a_2$. So, finally you can check whether the values that you got satisfy the actual inequalities.